# Old scifi movie where aliens disguise as humans

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I am looking for an old scifi movie, described in the title. I watched it a few years in 2009 (I think) when I was looking for scifi movies to rent (Watched in English). The plot is on some aliens getting trapped on earth and later, to survive, they disguise themselves completely as humans.

When aliens come to civilisation, one 'real' human spies on the human-disguised aliens. Also a magical pool that gives these aliens energy or something related. This pool is able to make people young again (sortof like a healing Fountain of Youth).

Can't remember anything else, details a bit hazy, but the ending is probably where the humans help the aliens return"" Thank you in advance if you can remember this!

Comment: @Toby. Upvoted the whole question just for your comment :)

Comment: The pool itself had no special properties, it was just a swimming pool. The aliens used the pool to temporarily house their cocoons; it was the cocoons (or their contents) which emanated a life force that rejuvenated the human visitors/interlopers.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### [*Cocoon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoon_(film))

[image]

This movie was released in 1985, so it’s pretty old.

From Wikipedia, we have the aliens disguising themselves as humans:

> About 10,000 years ago, peaceful aliens from the planet Antarea set up
>   an outpost on the planet Earth, on an island later known to mankind as
>   Atlantis. When Atlantis sank, twenty aliens were left behind, kept
>   alive in large rock-like cocoons at the bottom of the Atlantic Ocean.
>   Now a group of Antareans have returned to Earth to collect them.
>   **Disguising themselves as humans, they rent a house with a swimming
>   pool, and charge the water with “life force” to give the cocooned
>   Antareans energy to survive the trip home.** They charter a boat from a
>   local captain named Jack, who helps them retrieve the cocoons. Jack
>   likes Kitty, a beautiful woman from the team who chartered his boat.
>   When he spies on her while she undresses in her cabin, Jack is shocked
>   when he discovers she is an alien. After the aliens reveal themselves
>   to him and explain what’s going on, he decides to help them.

And the people swimming in it and becoming youthful:

> **Three of its residents, Ben, Arthur, and Joe, often trespass to swim
>   in the pool next door, thinking the house to be unoccupied. They
>   absorb some of the life force, making them feel younger and stronger.**
>   Eventually caught in the act, they are given permission to use the
>   pool by the Antarean leader, Walter, on the condition that they do not
>   touch the cocoons or tell anybody else about it. Rejuvenated with
>   youthful energy, the three men begin to let the advantages of the pool
>   take hold as they are relieved of their ailments (such as Joe’s cancer
>   miraculously disappearing and Ben’s vision becoming clear, allowing
>   him to be able to drive a car once again).

Comment: Is there any twist to this movie? from the summary it sounds boring.

Comment: @Dennis Christian indeed there's a twist. But the main attraction of the movie is the no longer youthful actors __having the time of their life__.

Comment: If you think this sounds boring, wait until you read about Cocoon 2.

Comment: «released in 1985, so **it’s pretty old.**»  Be nice.  Not everyone here is still wet behind the ears.

Comment: @JDługosz - Ah, that was a reference to its description as "an **old** sci-fi film" in the question. Not a gratuitous comment.

Comment: @DennisChristian not if you were a 13-year old boy.  It had a three second nude scene with one of the female aliens in her human form.

Comment: @DennisChristian It's not an action blockbuster type of film, but it was very enjoyable, in the same vein as "Starman".

Comment: I also haven't seen Starman yet. Sounds like i've got some binging ahead of me :)

Comment: @Kevin Nice retort, you are right too. I was 12 when I saw that film. Plus I was always a big fan of Guttenberg.

Comment: @DennisChristian What you might call a twist is that the aliens were entirely benign, peaceful visitors, and it was the humans who caused all the drama - the usual trope is that the aliens are evil, conquering, malevolent, etc. The heroes of the movie, perhaps apart from Gutenberg's character, were the alien rescue team (characters played by Brian Dennehy, Tahnee Welch, et al). If you want dramatic tension, think about the threat to the survival of those poor stranded, cocooned aliens at the hands of those self-concerned humans.

Comment: "This movie was released in 1985, so it’s pretty old."

And I feel even older for you having said that...

Answer (score -1):

It is -Earth Girls Are Easy with one of the Wayans Brothers

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do note that [Adamant's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/161255/122024) of _Cocoon_ has already been marked as the [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) answer -- as denoted by the green tick to the left of that answer -- which means that the user who asked the [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/161254/122024) believes that that answer is correct. If you think they're mistaken, you should [edit] this answer to explain why you think _Earth Girls Are Easy_ is the correct answer.

Comment: While Earth Girls are Easy is a great movie with great actors, and it does have a pool (where the aliens' space ship crashes), there is no rejuvenation. I still think everybody should watch EGSE, though.